# Коммерческие приложения

Tags: sfml, ecommerce, c++

Всем доброго времени суток!

Собираюсь писать игру с небольшой коммандой. На данный момент делать коммерцию не собираемся, но в планах, если все пойдет хорошо, все же собираемся продавать.

Для написания будет использоваться SFML, которая распространяется по лицензии zlib. Пока больше никаких фреймворков и библиотек использоваться не будет. ЯП - C++, возможно использование каких либо скриптовых языков (скорее всего LUA Script), т.е. + к этому еще будут добавлены библиотеки для поддержки и обработки этих языков внутри приложения.

Вопрос в том, какие лицензии придется приобрести, когда будет совершен переход к коммерческому продукту, и вообще - нужны ли они будут при данных условиях?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Читайте лицензии. В случае с SFML никаких приобретений не потребуется.